# Use execCommand on click

Tags: contenteditable, execcommand

I am trying to make the currently selected node blue in font color. At the moment, I have the following code, which only makes text blue when highlighted and then clicked.

How would it be possible to make it so that when I click the text, the whole node changes its font color using execCommand?

```
$('[contenteditable]').bind('click', function() {
    currentSentence = window.getSelection().focusNode;
    caretPosition = window.getSelection().focusOffset;

    document.execCommand('ForeColor', false, '000');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`focusNode` will only give you the container node of the *focus* of the selection, which is the most recently moved selection boundary. If that is what you want, you can save the selection, set the selection to encompass `focusNode` and then call `document.execCommand()`. If you need to restore the selection, that's a more difficult problem.

Note that none of this will work in IE < 9, which doesn't support `window.getSelection()` or `Range` and instead has a completely different API.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/J6fAa/

Example code:

```
$('[contenteditable]').bind('click', function() {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var focusNode = sel.focusNode;
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(focusNode);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    document.execCommand('ForeColor', false, '000');
});
```